# Determine HTTP Protocol Version in ASHX Handler

Tags: asp.net, http, protocol-handler

Is it possible to determine the HTTP protocol version (e.g. 1.0 vs. 1.1) used for a request within a .ashx handler?  I can see all of the header information except for the version in Request.Params.

If not, what avenues are available to discover the HTTP protocol version when processing an HTTP request in ASP.Net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]`